# Android Bluetooth Communication call write medthod

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, communication

I am attempting to use the MyBluetoothService class straight from the Android tutorials and call the write method from the main activity as suggested by the text. I would just like some guidance on how to pass a string from the main activity to the write method and send it to a connected Bluetooth device.

```js
public class MyBluetoothService {
    private static final String TAG = "MY_APP_DEBUG_TAG";
    private Handler mHandler; // handler that gets info from Bluetooth service

    // Defines several constants used when transmitting messages between the
    // service and the UI.
    private interface MessageConstants {
        public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0;
        public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 1;
        public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 2;

        // ... (Add other message types here as needed.)
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
        private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
            // member streams are final.
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
            }
            try {
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream.
                    numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                    Message readMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                            MessageConstants.MESSAGE_READ, numBytes, -1,
                            mmBuffer);
                    readMsg.sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);

                // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
                Message writtenMsg = mHandler.obtainMessage(
                        MessageConstants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, mmBuffer);
                writtenMsg.sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);

                // Send a failure message back to the activity.
                Message writeErrorMsg =
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(MessageConstants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("toast",
                        "Couldn't send data to the other device");
                writeErrorMsg.setData(bundle);
                mHandler.sendMessage(writeErrorMsg);
            }
        }

        // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will help you to find all the devices in the surrounding

```
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle; 
    import android.view.View; 
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.List;
     import java.util.Set;

    public class DeviceList extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView blist;
    Button b;
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "device_address";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);



    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    blist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);



    myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(myBluetooth == null)
    {
        //Show a mensag. that the device has no bluetooth adapter
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Device Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //finish apk
        finish();
    }
    else if(!myBluetooth.isEnabled())
    {
        //Ask to the user turn the bluetooth on
        Intent turnBTon = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(turnBTon,1);
    }

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pairedDevices();
        }
    });

}
private void pairedDevices()
{
    pairedDevices=myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
    {

        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
        {
            list.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress()); //Get the device's name and the address
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Paired Bluetooth Devices Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    blist.setAdapter(adapter);
    blist.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener); //Method called when the device from the list is clicked

}


private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener myListClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3)
    {
        // Get the device MAC address, the last 17 chars in the View
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        // Make an intent to start next activity.
        Intent i = new Intent(DeviceList.this, ledControl.class);

        //Change the activity.
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address); //this will be received at ledControl (class) Activity
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
}
```

this code helps to send the message to the device connected

```
  public class ledControl extends AppCompatActivity {


Button btnOn, btnOff, btnDis;
TextView lumn;
String address = null;
private ProgressDialog progress;
BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = null;
BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private boolean isBtConnected = false;
//SPP UUID. Look for it
static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent newint = getIntent();
    address = newint.getStringExtra(DeviceList.EXTRA_ADDRESS); //receive the address of the bluetooth device

    //view of the ledControl
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_led_control);

    //call the widgtes
    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnDis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    lumn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lumn);

    new ConnectBT().execute(); //Call the class to connect

    //commands to be sent to bluetooth
    btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            turnOnLed();
            //method to turn on

        }
    });

    btnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            turnOffLed();   //method to turn off

        }
    });

    btnDis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Disconnect(); //close connection
        }
    });
}

private void Disconnect()
{
    if (btSocket!=null) //If the btSocket is busy
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.close(); //close connection
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { msg("Error");}
    }
    finish(); //return to the first layout

}

private void turnOffLed()
{
    if (btSocket!=null)
    {
        try
        {


            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("F".toString().getBytes());
            //Log.e("message",)
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
}

private void turnOnLed()
{
    if (btSocket!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            //Toast.makeText(ledControl.this,"oning",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btSocket.getOutputStream().write("O".toString().getBytes());
            Log.e("message",btSocket.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
        }
    }
}

// fast way to call Toast
private void msg(String s)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


private class ConnectBT extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  // UI thread
{
    private boolean ConnectSuccess = true; //if it's here, it's almost connected

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(ledControl.this, "Connecting...", "Please wait!!!");  //show a progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) //while the progress dialog is shown, the connection is done in background
    {
        try
        {
            if (btSocket == null || !isBtConnected)
            {
                myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();//get the mobile bluetooth device
                BluetoothDevice dispositivo = myBluetooth.getRemoteDevice(address);//connects to the device's address and checks if it's available
                btSocket = dispositivo.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);//create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                btSocket.connect();//start connection
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            ConnectSuccess = false;//if the try failed, you can check the exception here
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) //after the doInBackground, it checks if everything went fine
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!ConnectSuccess)
        {
            msg("Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again.");
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            msg("Connected.");
            isBtConnected = true;
        }
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a great lead so far, however the code fails at btSocket.connect() under the ConnectBT class. I am trying to connect to a raspberry Pi running python which I have confirmed makes an RFCOMM socket correctly, as input can be received when using the BlueTerm app. I receive "IO Exception: read failed, socket might be closed or timeout, read ret -1". Any idea why this might be happening?